# Timber plugin (Twig) does not show custom type posts in index page

Tags: custom-post-types

[Timber](https://wordpress.org/plugins/timber-library/) does not show custom type posts in index page.

**index.php:**

```
$context = Timber::get_context();
$context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts();
$context['foo'] = 'bar';
$templates = array('index.twig');
if (is_home()){
  array_unshift($templates, 'home.twig');
}
Timber::render($templates, $context);
```

**functions.php:**

```
function register_post_types(){
  register_post_type( 'test',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'test' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'test' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
    )
  );
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple quick notes before we get started:

1. I don't think this is a timber problem. (If it is, 3rd-party plugin/theme posts are off topic for this forum.)
2. Be careful about using generic sounding functions like `register_post_types()`. You never know when WordPress might introduce a function like that and it's generic enough that some other plugin or theme might think to use it too. So to avoid conflicts, you should always prefix your functions with your initials or a client accronym or, as in the answer below, your WPSE question #! If your post type is something common too (like person or business or project), give its slug a prefix too.

---

When you say "index page," I assume you mean your "page for posts" (aka "blog") which will use an `index.php` file in your theme if a `home.php` file isn't present.

However, if all you want is for a custom post type to show up on the page for posts page, you can do that with `pre_get_posts`! This goes with your `register_post_type()` function.

```
function wpse162065_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if( is_home() && is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'test' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse162065_pre_get_posts' );
```